# executing process while true during for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

My code basically goes like this

```
P = matrix # initialise value of P matrix
x = some other matrix

for i, val in enumerate(vals):

    lots of matrix calculations involving P and x

    y = z - j # this is the important line

    lots of matrix calculations UPDATING P and x

    return values of P and x for each step
```

now I want to change my code so that if y is greater than some threshold, say y>0.5, I reset P and x to their initial values - and continue the loop again as if it's just started from scratch. I'm not sure of the best way to do this, I'm new to python so any specific help at all would be really useful - I'm not sure if I should use another loop inside my for loop - or define my calculations in a function.

Cheers

S

Answer (score 1):

In python `list` is a mutable object. To start from scratch in middle of computation, maintain a deepcopy of original list and the re-assign P and x with the original values and continue. Something like this:

```
import copy
P = matrix # initialise value of P matrix
x = some other matrix
p1= copy.deepcopy(P)
x1= copy.deepcopy(x)
for i, val in enumerate(vals):
  lots of matrix calculations involving P and x
  y = z - j # this is the important line
  if y > threshold:
    P = p1
    x = x1
    continue
  lots of matrix calculations UPDATING P and x
  return values of P and x for each step
```

Comment: I'm working with numpy arrays, will the kind of method still  work??

Comment: Yes it will. 
copy.deepcopy: A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: Cool, just tried to implement this. It didn't work in my case - I'm not totally exactly why, but it proceeds to make every P and x value P1 and x1? I don't know if you can debug this with this little info, but might get back to you